# Dart SCSS rejecting $ syntax

Tags: dart, sass, scss-mixins, codekit

I'm using Codekit to compile and process `SCSS`, and recently it was recommended to upgrade from `Liblass` to `Dart`, for future proofing.

This seems to be an easy switchover, however I do have one snippet of code that is throwing an error during compilation. I wonder if anyone might be able to assist with? The error is: `Dart Sass failed with this error: Error: expected "$".`

The code in question is intended to iterate over a number of nth-child() elements and incrementally apply a transition-delay to them, increasing by 150ms per item.

```
@for $i from 1 to 50 {
  &:nth-child($i) { transition-delay: calc($i * 150ms); }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [interpolate](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) the variable:

```
@for $i from 1 to 50 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) { transition-delay: calc(#{$i} * 150ms); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This allows the code to compile, however it outputs into the .css file like this: :nth-child(#{1}), meaning it doesn't work on the front-end, it should be: :nth-child(1)

Comment: That's really weird! It works fine on SassMeister. Can you try the [loop example](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) given on the official documentation and see if it works?

Comment: No luck unfortunately, exactly the same error happens.

Comment: My original code does seem to have an error on SassMeister

Comment: I edited my answer to add the interpolation in the `calc()` function because it is also required here. As for the test on SassMeister, you need to put your code in a parent selector since it uses `&`. If the official example doesn't even work for you then the problem comes from elsewhere...

Comment: Spoke too soon unfortunately, still not working as you'd expect.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your compiler then, because this code works fine.